# AWS X-Ray doesn't show Authorizer in Service Map with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-xray, lambda-authorizer

API Gateway --> Custom Authorizer(Lambda) --> NLB --> Fargate Task

Above is the request flow of my application, I have enabled X-Ray in API Gateway stage and redeployed the API.

However, in the X-Ray trace map diagram, I see only API Gateway and NLB.

Trace maps is like this, API Gateway --> NLB.

1. What should I do to get the tracing of Custom Authorizer?
2. What should I do to get the tracing of NLB --> Fargate?

Answer (score 0):

In the Lambda console for your Custom Authorizer function, you should be able to check "Enable X-Ray Active Tracing" & add appropriate permissions to see the Lambda node: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html

To trace the Fargate task, include the X-Ray daemon in your task definition ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html)) and you will have to instrument your code with the X-Ray SDK. The X-Ray SDK is available in 6 languages and you can see documentation for getting started with them in the sidebar here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-gettingstarted.html